# How to change the charset in a HTTP Response in Java?

Tags: java, character-encoding, httprequest

I'm sending a HTTP GET request with java. See code below. 
When I parse the response, the german "Umlaute" (e.g. ß,ä,ü) are just rubbish characters. 
I know, it's something about charset, but what exactly do I have to do ?

This is part of the code:

```
URL obj = new URL( urlAsString );
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
on.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
```

Do I have to set a special request property or something like that ? Or do I have to convert the result somehow ?

When I enter the "urlAsString" in a web browsers address line, I get a perfect result and all "Umlaute" are correct.

thanks for any hint!
Thorsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the charset in the response part, not in the request part such as

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This part have to be correct as you said that it is ok when you test from the browser.

Now from the client part, that is in your java program you also have to set the header `Accept-Charset` that indicates to the server the charset that you can accept. For example for utf-8 then iso-8859-1 you can add this header :

```
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1;q=0.5
```

If it doesn't work, you could also try to read the bytes from the connection by specifying the charset such as :

```
DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ds, "UTF-8"));
```

Maybe that the problem is there but you don't show this part in the posted code.

Comment: It's working now! I added the "Charset..." thing to this code:                 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")) );

Comment: Great. The fact that it worked well from the browser gave good hints on the possible causes.

Comment: @user1119859 Note that not every HTTP response will return UTF-8 content.  The actual charset should be obtained from the response’s [Content-Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

can you try below like this ? Here you to set the content type and character set encoding for utf-8.

```
 URL obj = new URL( urlAsString );
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
 con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
 on.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
```

I will suggest to use Apache Http Client for better usage and flexibility.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this didn't work. Still the same result.

Comment: Can you provide the url ? By the way, you can what is coming from url in more details if you google chrome and press Ctrl+Shift+i for debugging and you can see the request and response param details. It wil give you more insight.